# CActiveDataProvider Querying on join

Tags: yii

I have a simple SQL query, which I need to convert to use in Yii 1.1.

```
SELECT * 
FROM User 
INNER JOIN Role ON Role.UserId = User.Id
WHERE Role.Name = 'admin'
```

How is this written into the CActiveDataProvider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have came up with an answer. Hopefully it helps someone in the future.

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider('User', array
(
     'criteria' => array
      (
          'with' =>'roles',
          'join' => 'INNER JOIN Role r ON r.UserId = User.Id',
          'condition' => 'r.Name=:term',
          'params' => array(':term'=>'admin')
      )
));
```